# MSSQL to MYSQL using CASE WHEN THEN SUBSTRING & CHARINDEX

Tags: mysql, sql-server, substring, case, concatenation

I am having some real difficulty converting the below MSSQL statement to produce the same results in MYSQL.

The MSSQL query is as follows:

```
SELECT Radius_AdslUser.Password, Radius_AdslIp.IpAdd, Route = 
CASE WHEN Radius_AdslIP.Route IS NULL 
THEN NULL 
WHEN Radius_AdslIp.TotalIp = 8 
THEN Radius_AdslIP.Ipadd + '/29 ' + SUBSTRING(Radius_AdslIp.Route, 10, Charindex(' ', Radius_AdslIp.Route) - 10) + ' 1' 
WHEN Radius_AdslIp.TotalIp = 4
THEN Radius_AdslIP.Ipadd + '/30 ' + SUBSTRING(Radius_AdslIp.Route, 10, Charindex(' ', Radius_AdslIp.Route) - 10) + ' 1' 
WHEN Radius_AdslIp.TotalIp = 16
THEN Radius_AdslIP.Ipadd + '/28 ' + SUBSTRING(Radius_AdslIp.Route, 10, Charindex(' ', Radius_AdslIp.Route) - 10) + ' 1'
END, AVPair = 
CASE WHEN Radius_AdslUser.bandcap IS NULL 
THEN NULL 
ELSE 'throttle=' + Radius_AdslUser.bandcap 
END, Radius_AdslIp.Subnet
FROM Radius_AdslUser,Radius_AdslIp
WHERE Username = 'username@test.tld'
AND Suspended = 0
AND Radius_AdslUser.IpAddId = Radius_AdslIp.IpAddId
```

Which produces the following result:

```
Password    IpAdd           Route                               AVPair  Subnet
kmbjdatr    10.0.0.1        10.0.0.1/29 10.0.0.0 1              NULL    255.255.255.255
```

The format of the tables are as follows:

Radius_AdslIp

```
IpAddId IpAdd           Subnet          TotalIp UsableIp    Route                                   TypeId
944     10.0.0.1        255.255.255.255 8       6           ip:route=10.0.0.0 255.255.255.248       4
```

Radius_AdslUser

```
Username                    Password    IpAddId
username@test.tld           kmbjdatr    944
```

I have substituted CHARINDEX for LOCATE and have used CONCAT but am not having much luck.

For example:

```
WHEN Radius_AdslIp.TotalIp = 8 THEN Radius_AdslIp.Ipadd = CONCAT(Radius_AdslIp.Ipadd, '/29 ')
```

The table formats in MYSQL are identical.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly does "not having much luck" mean? What results and/or errors do you get? And have you tried writing some very simple SELECT statements to make sure the functions are working as you expect, before putting everything together?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are not applying the `CONCAT` function correctly. Basically, a SQL Server expression like this:

```
column_name + 'constant string' + function_call() + @variable
```

would look like this in MySQL:

```
CONCAT(column_name, 'constant string', function_call(), @variable)
```

The particular wrong part in your excerpt seems to be `Radius_AdslIp.Ipadd =` (the one before `CONCAT`). Not sure what you meant by that, but in any event it's just not needed there.